# implement stl vector constructor using iterator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement std::vector with C++98.

And, I referred https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

So, in constructor, I coded the vector like following.

```cpp
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
{
...
}

template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
{
...
}
```

But, when I tested that vector in main, it didn't work as I want.

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    vector<int> vec(3, 100);
}
```

I wanted to call `explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())`, but the constructor with iterator was called.

So, my question is that

1. Why the constructor with iterator is called?
   Is this happened because of 'explicit'?
2. Should I use 'size_t' in main() to call the constructor with 'val'?
   Or, is there any way to check iterator?

sorry to bother you, but I really don't know why this happened...

Comment: There are some more details mentioned on [cppreference's page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Specifically "This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies LegacyInputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (3)." I don't know what mechanism is used to produce this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation will normally use some kind of type traits to enable/disable iterator version, depending on if the iterator type is really an iterator or not.

For example, it would conceptually be something like:

```
template <class InputIterator, typename = enable_if_t<IsIterator_v<InputIterator>>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIteratorLast)
```

(or more correct to avoid redefinition of templates which defere only in default template arguments, as stated in comments and under this [notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes):):

```
// this is more the way it's actually practically implemented
template <class InputIterator, enable_if_t<IsIterator_v<InputIterator>, int> = 0>
    vector(InputIterator first, InputIteratorLast)
```

where `IsIterator_v` is implementation defined **type trait** for testing iterator requirement.

So in your constructor example `vector(3, 100)` the iterator constructor version will then not participate in overload resolution.

In C++98 there is **no** `enable_if`, but also then the implementation would use similar kind of concept checks.

Comment: Your `enable_if` is buggy, you have to `enable_if_t<..., int> = 0`. Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes.

Comment: Yeah, but it's rather an implementation detail. Main point is using type traits to enable/disable overloads. Updated., Thanks.